# RegEx for searching a SOLR comma-separated list run by ColdFusion

Tags: solr, coldfusion

My SOLR search results contain topic IDs stored as a comma-delimited list in a variable typed as a string.  `2,7,45,865`

The user can search on one or more.

Using a wildcard around a term picks up false positives that are longer in length.  (For instance, `*1*` gets 10, 2198, etc.)

How to cfsearch for [beginning or ,]IDvalue[end or ,] ideally for all IDs at once?

`(4305 166)` finds only 4305 or 166, not any multiple values like 4305,900 or 166,712.

Comment: Lucene (and Solr) supports `field:/foo/` to do a regex search against tokens so you might have luck with that instead; but a proper solution would be to use a multivalued field. You can use an update request processor to do this automagically for you on the Solr side without any special handling on the indexing side (i.e. in CF).

Answer (score 1):

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/accessing-and-using-data/solr-search-support/solr-enhancements-in-coldfusion-10.html

"Type `string` cannot be searched with wild cards except *. Since strings are not tokenized, you cannot search any word in a string. For example, in the case of `str_s="All work and no play"`, you cannot search for `"play"` or `"work"` in this string.  Type `text` is tokenized and therefore you can search for any word in the text."

Therefore the next step is to add a new text field with the string data, and remove the commas.